# Converting word symbols to unicode characters

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a number of word documents containing symbols from the "Symbol Font" in word - a delta, for example. Those are treated specially in the sense that if you double-click on them in Word 2010, the symbol's dialog opens. With this dialog it is also possible to add corresponding characters using unicode codepoints - a unicode delta, for example.

The unicode delta doesn't open the symbol's dialog and can be exported as unicode as one would expect (this is my actual problem), unlike the symbols using the "Symbol Font".

So my question: Is there a way in word or an external tool, with which I can mass-process a larger number of word files to replace all the symbols with unicode characters?

Comment: See if the macros listed [here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/FindReplaceSymbols.htm) help, or can be suitably modified to get the job done.